# Comparing pairs of data, combining only sometimes

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd, combiners

I am using Spark. I have a `JavaPairRDD` of the form `<Documentname, Tuple2<Phrase, URL>>`.

I have basically checked to see if a phrase is in the page specified by the URL, resulting in the structure above.

Now, I have several overlapping phrases (i.e. "to be or" is in "to be or not to be"), and I want to remove these shorter phrases that are contained within the larger phrases.

I'm a bit new to Spark, so I'm not sure how to do this *within Spark*.

I know I could make a double nested loop and do it if I collect() the elements, but I am wondering if there is a way to do it within Spark with a reduction or aggregation.

Basically, I want a function that will check each pair of phrases and either return both phrases if one is not contained within the other or just one phrase if one is.

Alternatively, I would like to run some sort of filter to remove these shorter phrases.

Any ideas?

**Edit:** I'm thinking either CombinebyKey or AggregateByKey will work, but I have no idea how to use them in Java. What is a sequence / combiner function?

I want to combine several elements of > by key and have a list of the Tuples where one phrase is not contained within any of the others.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, `combineByKey` (and its derivates) can't transform your keys, so "to be or" and "to be or not to be" won't be considered equal for that purpose. Can you change the way you construct the original RDD so that keys are automatically normalised to longest values?

Answer (score 0):

if you'd group by key (documentName) you'd have a regular collection of phrases you can loop and process (per document). This would work as long as the total number of phrases is relatively small so the collection would fit in memory.

If you need to do this in a distributed manner you'd need to do a flatMap to convert the key to DodumentName+Phrase so that later you'd be able to reduce (combine) by similarity

Comment: I think I'm going to have to resort to a "non-spark" way of handling things. Yes the number of phrases I get at the end is relatively small, the problem is that it's still being processed in the Spark framework and has conconcurrency issues.